# If / else on Wordpress Get_Post_Status

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to create a field that show the post status with a custom background.

I'm using this code:

```
function post_status_function() {
    global $post;
    if(get_post_status($post->ID, "draft", true)){ 
        echo "<a style='text-transform: capitalize;
        font-weight: 500;
        background: red;
        color: white;
           padding: 5px 23px 5px 25px;
        border-radius: 40px;'>";
        echo  get_post_status($post->ID);
        echo "</a>";
    }else{
        echo "<a style='text-transform: capitalize;
        font-weight: 500;
        background: green;
        color: white;
           padding: 5px 23px 5px 25px;
        border-radius: 40px;'>";
        echo  get_post_status($post->ID);
        echo "</a>";
}
    
    
}
add_shortcode('post_status_shortcode', 'post_status_function');
```

The result is only showing the red background.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed

```
$poststatus = get_post_status($post->ID);
    
    if($poststatus == 'draft'){
```

I've created a variable for the result.