# Is There a Conditional to Check Whether Another Wordpress Page is Published?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

Is there a conditional I can place in the header.php template to determine if a specific page (by ID) is published or draft status? And this would NOT be for the current page being displayed. It would need to work on everything page/post on the website. I don't see any WP conditional tags that would do this -- unless I'm missing something.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Related [If / else on Wordpress Get_Post_Status](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67324617/2943403)